# Decoder inputs needed given 32 registers

Tags: memory, register, decoder

I have a couple of questions about decoders. My first is this:

If I have a register bank with 32 registers, how many inputs are needed for the decoder and why? I think that you need 5 inputs for this decoder because 2^5 is 32. However, I do not know why this would be the case, or if I am even correct.

I am also curious as to how many inputs are needed for a decoder if the memory has 1 million locations, and why.

Comment: number the registers in decimal and then number them in binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need 32 UNIQUE ADDRESS. So if you name your registers 0 to 31 you only need enought bits to represent 31 = b11111.

For the 1 million locations you will need 1million unique addresses. So if you start at zero then the highest address will be 999,999 = 11110100001000111111. So you would need 20bits.